# Where is my apartment located vs Where is located my apartment

Tags: questions, word-order

Which of the following is more suitable?

> 1. Where **is** my apartment **located**?
> 2. Where **is located** my apartment?

Comment: *Where is my apartment located?* is the grammatically correct one

Comment: The correct question for your second example is *Where is the location of my apartment?*

Comment: In *wh-* questions the subject inverts with the auxiliary only, not the entire verbgroup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only your example 1 is correct.

The verb "to be located" is the passive form of the less common verb "to locate" (in the corresponding active sense of deciding upon placement), so it is indeed a verb phrase, and your instinct is correct that it requires inversion when phrased as a question. However, when inverting word order to form a question, as in example 1, only invert subject (apartment) and helping verb (is), never the main verb (located).

However, the *answer* to the question, which is *not* inverted, would be constructed as

> Your apartment is located here.

---

By way of comparison, when asking the question,

> Where is she going?

You would never ask,

> Where is going she?

But you would answer,

> She is going there.